# UITableView - header height - entire screen

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have `UITableView` inside `UITableViewController`. I have set `UITableView` header and I want to set its height to be entire screen, so the first cell of table is outside the screen.

I have tried inside `viewDidLoad()`

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = MyHeader(frame: self.view.frame)
self.tableView.tableHeaderView?.layoutIfNeeded()
```

however, the height of header is not larger than screen because there is navigation bar offset.

Is there any solution beside calculating or subtracting height manually?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot measure the height of anything in `viewDidLoad`. Wait until `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, and look at the table view's frame height, remembering to subtract the `top` of the `adjustedContentInsets` (to take account of the nav bar).